# How to convert word-document to html file in azure website?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-word, office-interop, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to convert a document file (.docx) to html file (.html) using Microsoft.interopt.Word dll and with this below code,

```
ApplicationClass application = null;
object missing = Type.Missing;
try
{
    application = new ApplicationClass();
    application.Application.Visible = false;
    filenamewithoutextension = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
    filewithext = fileName;
    object obj2 = new object();
    obj2 = kblocalfiePath + filewithext;
    object obj3;
    obj3 = @"" + htmlPath + "1762" + ".html";                
    application.Visible = false;
    application.Documents.Open(ref obj2, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    object obj5 = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML;
    // SAVE THE WORD AS HTML DOC
    application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(ref obj3, ref obj5, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    application.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(application);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    GC.Collect();
    if (application != null)
    {
        application.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(application);
        application = null;
    }
    throw ex;
}
```

This code works fine in my local maachine but after deploying in azure as website then its not working.I think this is because of  microsoft word components are not installed in azure vm.

if so, Is there a way to install microsoft office in my azure vm where my site is hosted? since its website i am unable to logon to server and install the copoentns.
I tried using OpenXML dll but i am facing lot formatting issue in html page.Kindly suggest me a way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Interop libraries without installing office on machine that execute your code.

Interop libraries are just bridge to application(word, excel ...) without them on system library won't work.

You should consider some third party libraries.

Comment: And they are neither intended for or licensed for use on a server

Comment: As per my requirement i am not supposed to use third party libraries than codeplex dlls so I tried with open source dll called OpenXML but facing formatting issue,